# Difference between standard error and standard deviation?

Tags: r, excel, statistics, standard-deviation, standard-error

I have 2 samples. For each i calculate a number of objects, according to the time. I plot in the y axis the number of objects and in the x axis the time in hour.
In excel I have an option to plot error bars, using standard deviation or standard error.
I'd like to know what's the difference between them and if standard error are enough to show that the data of my two samples are significant?
Even after reading some definition on the internet, it's still very confusing to me, being a newbie on statistics.

This is my graph and by plotting the standard errors, this is what it gives. Probably not enough to judge the significance of my data?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics.

Comment: I suggest to get a textbook from the library.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you mean you have two sample populations, right? if you have two samples that means you have only 2 'records'.
Standard error refers to a "standard devation" that occurs with in a sample population. A standard deviation refers to a complete population.
Significance is usually derived with a formula that helps us understand if an 'effect' is from chance alone.

Also, if you really do meant that you only have two samples, it is not enough for statistical research. Most large studies use thousands of samples. However, for "statistical" purposes they taught me in a math class that 36 is generally acceptable, as long as theres no bias and it's for school-work. So.. I hope this helps.

edit: oh, a standard deviation indicated the "spread" of the data.. 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Standard_deviation_diagram.svg/350px-Standard_deviation_diagram.svg.png

Comment: Correct it then, or post the better answer, please. You're not helping OP with this.

Comment: This is completely off-topic and basic textbook knowledge. Thus, I've voted to close the question.

Comment: Much unfeeling, little sympathy.

Comment: CRBN thanks a lot for your answer, Indeed I meant 2 sample populations, each have about 4000 results and i'd like to see if the data I've found are significant. So in my case, i should be using standard errors rather than standard deviation?

Comment: Roland, sorry I don't really understand why it's off-topic?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure for the charts/graphs tool in excel.
However, from what I remember in class you want std error. But if you're trying to prove significance i think you need something more that i don't remember..
I know the function would be =STDEV.S(
Let me look a bit for ya'.
Think you could post an image of what your data looks like? either the graphs or the distribution so I can just mock up some fake data over here.

Comment: @posthume Read [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to learn what is on-topic here. You should use neither standard deviation nor standard error to judge significance. You should use confidence intervals or conduct a hypothesis test. Study a statistics textbook or ask a statistician for help.

Comment: @Roland He's asking about in in the context of excel, though.
"software tools commonly used by programmers"
I do a bit of development and use excel A LOT.

Comment: CRBN, thank you very much. Yes sure I'll post the figure now.

Comment: @CRBN This has nothing to do with Excel. They could ask exactly the same question if they produced the graph with a different software. If they asked on stats.stackexchange.com the chance to get a low quality answer would be much lower (as you've demonstrated).

Comment: Roland, this has to do with Excel in the sense that i was wondering if those options (error bars) are good enough to test significance of data. You're saying it's off-topic for me to ask this, so sorry and thanks again for your time to reply.

Comment: I still appreciate CRBN's answer.

Comment: The question of whether something is "good enough to test significance" is a stats question. You can use stats.stackexchange.com for stats questions, as pointed out by @Roland. As much as you appreciate the current answer, I honestly think you'll benefit by asking the question again over there and reading their answers (although there's a good chance they've already covered it).

Comment: Ok ping thank you for this precision, I didn't know there was a "stat" category. Thanks again.